# PHP Oracle Query With Symbol Values

Tags: php, oracle

I tried query my code below on TOAD is OK.

```
SELECT * FROM SEIAPPS_T_CAL_REGISTRATION WHERE EQP_REF_NO = 'NE-TH#2-3'
```

When I query it on PHP application side, it's now worked.

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM SEIAPPS_T_CAL_REGISTRATION WHERE EQP_REF_NO = 'NE-TH#2-3'";
$result_q = oci_parse($c1, $q);
oci_execute($result_q);

if(oci_fetch($result_q) > 0)
{
    echo "Found";
}
else
{
    echo "Not found";
}
```

It always shows not found.

Please help.

I think the problem results from query value with Symbol. Maybe.

Comment: you're simply assuming the query suceeded. if the parse/execute stages fail, then fetch will simply return a boolean false because there's nothing valid to fetch from. Never EVER assume that a query will suceed. always assume failure, test for it, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 1):

I think `if(oci_fetch($result_q_chk) > 0)` should be `if(oci_fetch($result_q) > 0)`

If I am correct, $result_q_chk is a typo